# fpdf spacing between pictures in python?

Tags: python, image, margin, fpdf

I have found good code for making my all `.img` in one big pdf but I have a little problem.
I don't know how rules for the margin between pictures work.
I have a variable number of pictures in my directories, 66 pictures, in others 32, 72, and I would like 4 pictures per row and 4 per column, and after that, create another page in my pdf, is it possible?

my function

```
class MyFPDF(FPDF):
     pass
def photos_pdf():
    pdf = MyFPDF("L", format='A4', unit='mm')
    photos = glob.glob(filePath1 + "/*")
    x = 5 # marge gauche
    y = 5 # marge haute
    counter = 0
    nbre = 3 # NOMBRE DE VIGNETTES PAR LIGNES
    nbre_par_page = 9
    counter2 = 0
    pdf.add_page()
    for photo in photos:
        if counter2 != nbre_par_page:    
            if counter != (nbre):
                pdf.image(photo, x=x, y=y, w=63, h=88)
                x += 79
                counter += 1
                counter2 += 1
            else:
                counter = 0
                x = 20
                y += 72
        else:
            pdf.add_page()
            counter = 0
            counter2 = 0
            x = 20
            y = 10
    pdf.output(filePath1 + "/A4_cards.pdf", 'F')
photos_pdf()
```

Answer (score 0):

First change

`nbre = 4 # NOMBRE DE VIGNETTES PAR LIGNES` also `nbre_par_page = 16`

that should initiate layout 4x4

But you then need the size of img to fit the existing margins first, so try -out

`pdf.image(photo, x=x, y=y, w=47, h=66)`

then adjust those and the other values to see the effects.

[image]

For a Landscape layout you would need to keep a second copy with different values where width is larger than height accordingly.

Comment: thank for answer, i'm sorry, i would like 3 pictures by row and 9 by pages but it's not work, i have the 4 picture in totaly in right pdf